# Error in synching - Salesforce for Outlook

Tags: salesforce-for-outlook

We recently migrate users from One org to a new org.

I logged into to new salesforce org and downloaded and installed the new Sf FOR  Outlook, but while running sync process, I am  getting the below error.

But i see ISALLDAYEVENT is an standard field and it is available.

> ERROR at Row:1:Column:136 No such column 'ISALLDAYEVENT' on entity
>   'Event'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to
>   append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your
>   WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. --->
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: INVALID_FIELD: 
>   ActivityDateTime,Description,id,ACTIVITYDATE,ISALLDAYEVENT,ISEXCEPTION,ISRECURRENCE

Answer (score 3):

I believe you want to check (enable) the Field-Level-Security for the "All Day Event" field - for whatever profiles you are using.

We had this exact same error - and it was because the profiles did not have access to the field (there is a "Is Visible" property for the "All Day Event" field that needed to be enabled).

Answer (score 1):

1. Please check field mapping in the Salesforce for Outlook Configuration to ensure you have all the fields and mapped properly.
2. Try to check the  the Visibility and Field Accessibility Settings:
   Setup -> Customize -> Activities -> Event Fields -> Click on the required field name and then click 'Set Field-Level Security' to check the Visibility settings for the Profile that you are using. Also check the Field Accessibility.
3. Also if you are an admin and trying to Sync based on your profile and later on your users have to login using a different profile - you may land up into the same issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Both of them Have a point.

FLS is the most common culprit for these errors. You can also check the page layout of the login that is having that issue.